# In Angular how to change a field member in a component or service automatically, when another depending field member changes?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  fieldA = "";
  fieldB = `Hello ${this.fieldA}`;
  
  changeFieldA(){
    this.fieldA = "World";
  }
}
```

When the "changeFieldA" method is triggered, as I found at this moment, fieldB is still "Hello ", rather than "Hello World". I want to make fieldB "reactive" to fieldA, so that whenever fieldA's value changes, fieldB's value will instantly change at that moment.

I don't want to add an extra line of code in the "changeFieldA" method, like:

```
this.fieldB = `Hello ${this.fieldA}`;
```

so as to manually update the fieldB. I want to make the updating process totally automatic, because in the project I have a field which is a large nested object containing nested arrays, which makes the manual update like this very trivial.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways of doing it, but the simplest way for this particular case would be to call a function within `changeFieldA` that resets the value of `fieldB`. For instance:

```
private syncFieldB() {
  this.fieldB = `Hello ${this.fieldA}`;
}
      
changeFieldA(){
  this.fieldA = "World";
  this.syncFieldB();
}
```

The complicated logic of setting `fieldB` can be contained in the `syncFieldB` function. If you need the value of `fieldB` to be set whenever the value of `fieldA` is modified (perhaps outside of the `changeFieldA` function), then maybe you could use get/set:

```
private _fieldA = "";

get fieldA() {
  return this._fieldA;
}

set fieldA(value) {
  this._fieldA = value;
  this.syncFieldB();
}
```

This method doesn't require you calling `syncFieldB` wherever you modify `fieldA`.

Answer (score 0):

You could change

```js
fieldB = `Hello ${this.fieldA}`;
```

to

```js
get fieldB() {
  return `Hello ${this.fieldA}`;
}
```

so that fieldB is a read-only computed property.

However, it's probably better to replace the `fieldB` property with a method, not a getter, because those confuse people, *including you* when you come back to this code months and months later. ;-)